# laravel excel (download,export) object not found

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel

Need your help guys Im new to Laravel 5 and Im using Laravel Excel 2.0.8,

Followed Installation guide:
-composer.json (Done)
-composer update (Done)
-app.php (Done)
-aliases (Done)
-vendor:publish (Done)

But when i try a simple download() or export() on a controller

```
Excel::create('Names', function($excel)
        {
          $excel->sheet('Names', function($sheet)
          {
             $sheet->fromArray(array(
                    array('name1', 'name3'),
                    array('name2', 'name4')
                ));
          });
        })
        ->download('xls');
```

I get the error

> FatalErrorException in excel.php line 39:Call to a member function download() on a non-object

Answer (score 1):

instead of download  use export

```
Excel::create('Names', function($excel)
{
    $excel->sheet('Names', function($sheet)
    {
        $sheet->fromArray(array(
             array('name1', 'name3'),
             array('name2', 'name4')
        ));
      });
     })
        ->export('xls');
```